# create react app with github pages, not updating

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've used create-react-app and deployed it to my github pages site following instructions from this site https://hackernoon.com/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages

however whenever I change contents of my App.tsx file and then push changes to master, the github pages site doesn't reload with the changes. Am I  supposed to push changes to the gh-pages branch instead?

Comment: First of all, make sure that your GitHub page is running on which branch of your repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install `git` and `gh-pages`? Then, your `package.json` looks like something like this.

```
"scripts": {
    deploy: "gh-pages -d build",
    predeploy: "npm run build"
  },
```

After that, you create `repository` in github. Get repository url. For first deploy.

```
git init
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin YOUR_REPOSITORY_URL
npm run deploy
```

For next update. only `npm run deploy`.

Comment: So if I ever update the code all I need to do is npm run deploy? No need to push or commit?

Comment: yes. You already initiated git. But even if you reinitiated git, it won't matter as long as same repo url.